# Display "view discussion (n)" or otherwise indicate that there is a discussion

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, documentation

I started a discussion [on an Example over here](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/r/9039/publishing#t=201702091810449873722).`*` No one will ever see that discussion unless they really go hunting for it because...

- I just created the Topic, so no one is following its discussions.
- Anyone who sees the Topic has no reason to expect active discussions and so won't bother clicking the "discussion" tab. After all, most Topics don't have discussions visible there (either because none have ever been started or because they've been buried by "approved change" items).
- Assuming visitors don't click the discussion tab, there is no indication whatsoever that there is an active discussion (on the Example or on the Topic). It's arguably worse for the Topic, since its discussions will auto-close after 14 days.

So, I'd like to see, when browsing a Topic, an indication when there is an active conversation. My suggestion:

> Display "view discussion (n)" under each Example whenever n -- the number of comments on the Example within the last 14 days -- is above zero.
>
> Similarly, change the discussion tab name to "discussion (n)" whenever n -- the number of comments anywhere under the Topic in the last 14 days -- is above zero.

This is similar to the "request improvement (1)" seen currently on the linked page and to indicators used elsewhere on the site (for close votes and delete votes). The only difference is the time limit, without which this feature would be less informative.

---

*`*`Yes, I know the Example (which I wrote) is terrible; I'm hoping this is very short-term placeholder content.*

Comment: I _think_ we added that at some point and I never got around to marking this as complete. (See the [Wayback Machine archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20170816211636/https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/r/9039/publishing#t=201708162116363217346) to see how it looked.)

Comment: @Jon Ah, indeed, that's it. Btw, thanks for comments on these issues as you've been closing them; they provide interesting perspective on the project.